# JAVA Formula for the calculation of the area of a pentagon

Tags: java, formula

I hope you can help me out with this. I am trying to find the area of a pentagon. I know the formula however my answer does not match the correct answer.

I should be able to get the area by utilizing the math.sqrt but I am having a rough time simplifying the formula and combining it in such a way that the output is correct.

Here is my code

```
System.out.println("What shape do you need to know the area of?\n" +
    "1: Determine the Area of a Square?\n" +
    "2: Determine the Area of a Circle?\n" +
    "3: Determine the Area of a Ellipse?\n" +
    "4: Determine the Area of a Pentagon? \n" +
    "5: Exit\n"     
    );

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Selection: ");
    int input = reader.nextInt();
    reader.nextLine();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    }
if (input == 4){
        System.out.println("What is a length of 1 side of the Pentagon? ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
    // Calculate the area based on formula
        double area = (n * Math.pow(n, 2)) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / n));
    //Print result
        System.out.println (" Area of regular pentagon is " + area);
    }
```

Comment: Well, what is the reference formula you are using?

Comment: Give an example... for some `n` what do you expect and what do you actually get?  Looking at your code, a quick guess is that you're mixing integer and float/double arithmetic. Receive the input as an int then convert it to a double; use the double in the calculation.

Comment: looking at the formula it seems you are using n for the number of sides and for the side length. I guess the first and last occurance of n should actually be 5 instead.

Comment: Formula - A = 1/4 sqrt of 5(5 + 2sqrt of 5) a^2

Answer (score 1):

```
double area = (n * Math.pow(n, 2)) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI / n));
```

The above is not the correct formula (n=length of side) for area of a regular pentagon. The correct formula is

```
double area = (5 * n * n)) / (4.0 * Math.tan(Math.PI / 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's five time the size of one of the triangles comprising the pentagon.

If you have trouble figuring out the area of that triangle, remember it's 1/2 the area of the parallelogram comprised of two of those triangles stuck together (with equal angles across the diagonal joining the triangles)

If you have trouble figuring out the area of a parallelogram, it's the length of one of the parallel sides times the perpendicular distance between the parallel sides.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon) gives a formula for the area of a pentagram as 1.72 * n^2
You can use area=1.720477*n*n for a little more precision

Answer (score 0):

Area for *regular* pentagons is =~ `1.7204774*s^2`, being `s` the side of the pentagon, thus you should replace your calculation with:

```
// Calculate the area based on formula
    double area = (n * n * 1.7204774);
```

Comment: A value of the numeric constant more appropriate for double precision calculation is 1.7204774005889669